# Exponential Backoff With Google API PHP Client Library

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am running a web app to get a list of users with Google API PHP Client Library 2.0.3. and save them to a CSV file and at the same time, I am tracking the process on screen. The code I am using is the following:

```
$pageToken = null;
$optParams = array(
    "customer" => "my_customer",
    "maxResults" => 500,
    "orderBy" => "email",
    "sortOrder" => "ASCENDING"
);

try {

    $usernum = 0;

    do {

        if ($pageToken){
            $optParams['pageToken'] = $pageToken;   
        }           

        $results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);
        $pageToken = $results->getNextPageToken();
        $users = $results->getUsers();

        foreach ($users as $user) {

            $usernum++; 

            $csvfileusers = array($user->getPrimaryEmail());
            fputcsv($savecsv, $csvfileusers);

            $usersemails = $user->getPrimaryEmail();
            print "<li>".$usernum." - <font color='#9dd7fb'>".$usersemails."</font></li>";

        }

    } while($pageToken); 

} catch (Exception $e) {

    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();

}
```

Everything works fine. The problem is that from time to time I am getting `{ error: { errors: [ { domain: global, reason: backendError, message: Service unavailable. Please try again } ], code: 503, message: Service unavailable. Please try again } }`

I know this means that I am sending requests to Google Server too fast hence I need to implement an exponential backoff solution. My problem is that I don't know how to do that. Would someone be kind enough to provide me an example on how to do that using the PHP Client Library? I know that I might be able to figure this out at the long term but if I can get some help I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after 20 days of trying and investigating and thanks to the information provided by @kyle, I came up with this exponential backoff solution.

```
$attemptNum = 1; // retry attempt
$expBackoff = false; // exponential backoff rety indicator

do {

    if($attemptNum <= 4) {
        try {

            $usernum = 1;

            do {

                if ($pageToken){
                    $optParams['pageToken'] = $pageToken;   
                }           

                $results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);
                $pageToken = $results->getNextPageToken();
                $users = $results->getUsers();

                foreach ($users as $user) {

                    $csvfileusers = array($user->getPrimaryEmail());
                    fputcsv($savecsv, $csvfileusers);

                    $usersemails = $user->getPrimaryEmail();
                    print "<li>".$usernum." - <font color='#9dd7fb'>".$usersemails."</font></li>";
                    $usernum++; 

                }

            } while($pageToken); 

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $err503ReasonA = "Service unavailable"; // Service unavailable.
            $err503ReasonB = "Backend Error"; //Backend Error

            $exception = $e->getMessage();

            if(strpos($exception, $err503Reason) !== false || strpos($exception, $err503ReasonB) !== false){    
                $expBackoff = true;
                $sleeptime = $retrynum * 1; //retrynum * seconds
                sleep($sleeptime);
                $retrynum++;
            } else {
                $expBackoff = false;
                print "There was an error -> $exception";
            }
        }

    } else {
        $expBackoff = false;
    }

} while ($expBackoff);
```

I have been trying this solution for two days now and it has worked like a charm. Hopefully this might be helpful for someone else. I´m happy now. :)

Comment: does this block the application?

Comment: @arecaps Not as far as I'm concerned. Or what exactly do you mean by "block the application"?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the documentation is [lacking for the actual backoff implementation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#implementing_exponential_backoff).  However, the Google_Task_Runner class outlines the backoff implementation process.  [You can see how it does it here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Task/Runner.php).

However, based on what you're doign you don't actually want to implement a [exponential backoff procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) in general networking terms.  You're really wanting to just throttle the request so you don't slam the API.  Depending on how many `$pageToken` you're iterating over, you could just do a [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) before doing the next while iteration.

Additionally, what does `$pageToken = $results->getNextPageToken();` become after one request? Becuase you're setting that from the response rather than decrementing it programatically, which may be causing an infinute loop or something of that nature.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I will look into this and get back to you.